# Jmeter - Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException is observed on trying to record a script for 1 user

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record a login scenario for my application built using Blazor technology through Templates (File > Templates > Recording) for a single user.
I see that few of the initial sampler results are successful and then I see the below error in View Results Tree. Error is constant on trying many times.

**Sampler Result**

```
Thread Name:

Sample Start:2021-01-12 09:35:17 GMT

Load time:21037

Connect Time:21037

Latency:0

Size in bytes:2582

Sent bytes:0

Headers size in bytes:0

Body size in bytes:2582

Sample Count:1

Error Count:1

Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text

Response code:Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException

Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connect to push.services.mozilla.com:443 [push.services.mozilla.com/44.238.116.130] failed: Connection timed out: connect


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

**Response Data:**

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to push.services.mozilla.com:443 [push.services.mozilla.com/44.238.116.130] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:930)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:641)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1281)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:234)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(LazyLayeredConnectionSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 14 more
```

**In the logs, I see errror in**

```
Line 2: 2021-01-12 09:34:16,562 ERROR f.configuration: DefaultObjectWrapper.incompatibleImprovements was set to the object returned by Configuration.getVersion(). That defeats the purpose of incompatibleImprovements, and makes upgrading FreeMarker a potentially breaking change. Also, this probably won't be allowed starting from 2.4.0. Instead, set incompatibleImprovements to the highest concrete version that's known to be compatible with your application.

Line 3: 2021-01-12 09:34:16,562 ERROR f.configuration: Configuration.incompatibleImprovements was set to the object returned by Configuration.getVersion(). That defeats the purpose of incompatibleImprovements, and makes upgrading FreeMarker a potentially breaking change. Also, this probably won't be allowed starting from 2.4.0. Instead, set incompatibleImprovements to the highest concrete version that's known to be compatible with your application.

Line 72: 2021-01-12 09:37:39,166 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [53022]  Problem with SSL certificate for url  for 'incoming.telemetry.mozilla.org'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

**NOTE :**

I have tried recording using the Non HTTP Script Recorder too - same issue.

I see this issue when application is launched on a test server with no internet connection.

I see this issue when the application is hosted locally on the same test server.

Also in UI - Page contents    do not load and login page is displayed as a blank page with only the    page title and page url as expected.

The application URL is of the format https://abcd.com:1234/login

I have updated the port number in JMeter and Firefox browser as 8888

Root CA certificate is added.

I see the same issue even after increasing timeout to 60000 in HTTP Request defaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the `push.services.mozilla.com` hostname it appears that JMeter catches requests to [Firefox Web Push notifications service](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox) (allowing websites to send notifications to you)

I don't think you should be recording these requests (unless you're explicitly testing them) so you should add this `push.services.mozilla.com` to "URL Patterns to Exclude" section of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

[image]

More information: [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)

You should repeat the exercise for all the requests to/from 3rd-party domains if any so your test scope would be limited to your system under test only